# CSS reacts weird on Safari

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and it's nearly finished, but then I landed on a big problem. My website works perfect on Chrome, Firefox and IE, but in Safari it's totally out of control.

What is the cause of this?

Here is the link: http://www.ik-ben-zzp.nl/testsite/

EDIT:

These are 3 of the issues that only occur on Safari and not on other browsers. all of these problems have to be centered and aligned and they are not on Safari. Is there any cause?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, please post a specific description of the issue, not some link to some arbitrary site in the internet.

Comment: I put your site into a couple of browsers and it doesn't look the same in any two of them. Also, you have 24 errors; maybe tend to those first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your CSS rules for `transform` and some others are missing the vendor prefixes Safari needs to display them properly.

Here's one example, this pre-fixed rule is missing from line 141 of your CSS:

`-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;`

More info here: http://shouldiprefix.com/#transforms

Although as someone pointed out in the comments, you really should fix those errors appearing in the console first, before attempting to debug your problem.